# What is the way to draw a string with all characters equally wide in terms of pixels?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, drawstring

```
  Bitmap bmpChar = new Bitmap(16,16);       
  FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");

  Font font = new Font(
               fontFamily,
               16,
               FontStyle.Regular,
               GraphicsUnit.Pixel);


  Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(testBmp);
  g.DrawString("test", font, Brushes.Red, 0, 0);
```

Upper code prints two characters in 16x16 area(it has "te" of "test" while I expected only a "t"). Whats could be a platform-independent(32-bit, 64bit, NT, XP, 7, 10) way to have constant width characters for all letters and numbers when drawing them as strings onto a bitmap, in winforms?

Comment: Try Lucidia Console or Courier which are fixed width fonts.

Comment: Use a mono space font.

Comment: Select a monospaced font. Like Courier, Consolas...

Comment: Or draw the letters individually...

Comment: Drawing individually is harder but I will try mono space. I wish its defaultly installed in   all windows.

Comment: Drawing letters individually is not a good idea in some languages. For example if you draw `سلام` letters individually, it would be `س ل ا م` which is not equivalent to the input string.

Comment: I'll use just a-zA-Z0-9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) if it's possible. Otherwise you'd just be either stretching the letters out after rasterization or having to calculate the amount of spacing to put in between each letter which would be a lot more complicated.

Comment: Tested with generic monospace but with 16px again, it rendered t and half of e in 16x16 area. Maybe monospace can't be at certain resolutions? Ok, using 24 as size solved it, with generic monospace.